# magento 2 - No Payment Methods

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

I am working with magento 2, I created an e-commerce site and everything works fine, but suddenly the payment page displays **No Payment Methods**.

I cleared the browser cache, but the problem persists.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's working well for me.such a nice answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same issue for me so i have Create checkout_index_index XML file and put to below location **theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/checkout_index_index.xml** 
and Put Below Content in your XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Than Check its working for me. .

Comment: Wow, how is this possible, can you explain it ?
It works !

Comment: Wow, awesome!!!Can you please explain how it works?